# Is distributivity equivalent to factorization?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, arithmetic

In a ring, mutiplication distributes over addition. So, given a product of a sum $a \cdot (b + c)$, we can write it as a sum of products $(a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$. Conversely, given a sum  of products $(a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$, we can "factor out" the common factor $a$ and write the expression as a product of a sum $a \cdot (b+c)$.

Distributing a factor over a sum and factoring out a common factor out of a sum seem like *inverse* processes, and, moreover, they seem equivalent. That is, an arithmetic object admits one if and only if it admits the other. Is this true?

(If that's true, then the axiom of distributivity could always be replaced by an axiom of "factoring", but I've never seen that.)

Comment: It seems to me you are just asking why we write "$\forall a,\forall b,\forall c,\ a(b+c)=(ab)+(ac)$" rather than "$\forall a,\forall b,\forall c,\ (ab)+(ac)=a(b+c)$". As for why it's called "distributivity", I presume it's because "factoring out" is perceived, linguistically, as a property of the specific $a$ ("$a$ can be factored out"), while "distributivity" is perceived as property of the operation ("product is distributive over sum").

Comment: "factoring" and "distributing" are just two aspects of the distributivity axiom. One is reading it forward, one is reading it backward. There's no "directionality" implied in the axioms you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a(b+c) = ab + ac$ is true for $a, b, c$ in your algebraic structure (even if it is not true in general, but only for specific $a, b, c$), then the equality is true regardless of which direction you read it.

As for why the axiom doesn't have a separate name, why should it? It's the same law.